# What are $C^1$ vector fields and how are they defined?

Tags: calculus, notation, vector-fields

$C^1$ functions are defined as those which are differentiable and their first derivative is continuous. What are $C^1$ vector fields and how are they defined?

Comment: Vector fields are functions and $C^1$ vector fields are vector fields which are $C^1$ functions.

Comment: We need more context: Where have you heard about vector fields? On which sets do $C^1$ functions and $C^1$ vector fields live?

Comment: The answer is found here  in the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness